# How to bind multiple values using PDO prepared statements?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

Here is my code

```
$bindParams = [
'name1'  => 'Law',
'name2'  => 'King'
              ];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (:name1),(:name2);";

$db->prepared_query($sql,$bindParams);



class Database
{
public function __construct
(
    public \PDO $PDO
)
{}

public function prepared_query(string $sql='',$bindParams=[]): bool
{
    $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare($sql);

    if(count(value:$bindParams) !=0)
    {
        foreach ($bindParams as $k => $v)
        {
            $stmt->bindParam(param:":$k",var:$v);
        }
    }
    $x = $stmt->execute();

    if($x)
    {
        return true;
    }else{
             return false;
         }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that in the foreach loop the second value from array $bindParams having key name2 and value king is overriding $stmt->bindParam and only name2 king is inserted in the database. And for every insert I am getting king in database. Here is screen shot of database. How can I insert both records from array sucessfully without repetition.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to remove the `foreach` and just pass the parameter to  `$x = $stmt->execute($bindParams);`

Comment: @Nigel Ren I don't want to pass the array $bindParams to execute function. Can you suggest me some other way to duplicate this $stmt->bindParams() for every key of the array?? and then perform $stmt->execute() on all of them in single attempt ??

Comment: Why don't you want to pass them to `execute()`, it's a common practice?

Comment: I wanted to know the other way around just for knowledge..:) @Nigel Ren

Comment: @Nigel Can you please edit the code and post ?

Comment: Think an alternative is $stmt->bindValue($k,$v);`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the parameter in `execute()`. There is no need to use `bindParam()` which binds by reference and will overwrite your values inside a loop.

Replace your code with this:

```
public function prepared_query(string $sql, array $bindParams=[]): void
{
    $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($bindParams);
}
```

If you really want to have a loop, which you really do not need, then you have to bind by value and not by reference. e.g.

```
public function prepared_query(string $sql, array $bindParams = []): void
{
    $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($bindParams as $param => $var) {
        $stmt->bindValue($param, $var);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: I believe an empty array works as well as a null value

Comment: @ Dharman $stmt->execute() assumes that all array values provided are PDO::PARAM_STR . What if we have set a column data type in the tables as int and then a string value is provided instead of int in that case?? How to make that PARAM int??

Comment: @King619 It doesn't matter 99.99% of the time. You can bind almost everything as string. If you really need to cast it as an integer then you can use `bindValue`. This is the second examples I provided.